# Yahoo local supported countries and alternatives

Tags: api, local, yahoo

I want to use yahoo local api for India, is India supported?

What are the other alternatives for yahoo local, does google have similar api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Google Places API which is similar to yahoo local API

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/